# Firedac component does not show query window

Tags: delphi, firedac

Any TFDQuery that I put on the screen and try to give 2 clicks to edit it does not bring the window front. I tried looking at the .dfm (window size) and .pas files and it's all right. He apparently opens the window, only shows nothing later. I have to give ALT F4 to close the invisible window and go back to the project. Delphi XE6. This happens in existing projects and new projects.

Comment: Are you talking about `TFDQuery` design time editor? You have used that at runtime in your application, or what's this about?

Comment: that's it. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/images/RADStudio/Tokyo/e/d/d2/AD_QueryDlg.png

Comment: @Victoria I restored backup on another computer and the error persisted. I try to reinstall without backup, however my components are so many, it gives sad to reinstall them.

Comment: @PabloAquino What happen when you right-click on the `TFDQuery` component?

Comment: @Sami The menu appears and I click on query editor ... The same problem happens. I've tried resizing the windows screen, see if it appears somewhere. Maximize resolution, minimize resolution. The little window does not appear.

Comment: the repair using the installer did not solve.

Comment: I still don't understand. You're showing that dialog at runtime, or you have problem at design time? If runtime, just show that dialog as modal (if that's the desired behavior).

Comment: @Victoria design time.

Comment: Aha, I thought you're talking about runtime. I have no Delphi XE6 by hand, so I can only say I can't reproduce this in Tokyo :( From what you describe sounds like design time editors are registered but something prevents them from being displayed. Tokyo shows that form modal (from the `TfrmFDGUIxFormsQEdit.ExecuteBase` method). Can you check if it's shown modal in your version too?

Comment: @Victoria I'm doing a new installation. If you do not succeed, I'll see. Thank you very much .

Comment: Sounds like the window is restored to a position off the monitor. You can press "Alt-Space" to pull up the system menu. Then arrow down to the "move" option and press enter. Then Click your right arrow key to capture the mouse. Then a mouse move should bring the screen into view. It's been a few years since I needed those keystrokes to pull a windows back, but it appears to work for the query editor window.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. There is no "show" on the form. But thanks.

Comment: @PabloAquino- the fact that you need to press Alt-F4 to close the window indicates it is shown. Just press Alt-Space instead of Alt-F4 to get the system menu.

Comment: @MarkElder It was the first thing I did. Did not work.